# Pre-Populated Room Database shows empty ArrayList

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room

I'm following a tutorial on MVVM and using Room and Viewmodel. I manually inserted a few items into the database and it's supposed to update a RecyclerView with these items. Still, when I run it the arrayList attached to the adapter is showing 0. I'm not sure where I went wrong since I followed a tutorial, but after checking the steps a few times I'm still stuck

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        NoteAdapter noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);

        noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);

        //noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
                noteAdapter.setNotes(notes);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private NoteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;


    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Note note){
        repository.insert(note);
    }

    public void update(Note note){
        repository.update(note);
    }

    public void delete(Note note){
        repository.delete(note);
    }

    public void deleteAllNotes(){
        repository.deleteAllNotes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class NoteRepository {
    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

    public NoteRepository(Application application){
        NoteDatabase database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application);
        noteDao = database.noteDao();
        allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Note note){
        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void update(Note note){
        new UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void delete(Note note){
        new DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void deleteAllNotes(){
        new DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes(){
        return allNotes;
    }

    private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>{
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao){
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>{
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private UpdateNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao){
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            noteDao.update(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class DeleteNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>{
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private DeleteNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao){
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            noteDao.delete(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao){
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            noteDao.deleteAllNotes();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note currentNote = notes.get(position);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(currentNote.getDescription());
        holder.tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(currentNote.getPriority()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public void setNotes(List<Note> notes){
        this.notes = notes;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView tvTitle;
        private TextView tvDescription;
        private TextView tvPriority;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            tvPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority);
        }
    }
```

Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static NoteDatabase instance;

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

    public static synchronized NoteDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    NoteDatabase.class, "note_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };

    private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        public PopulateDbAsyncTask(NoteDatabase db){
            noteDao = db.noteDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 1", "Description 1", 1));
            noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 2", "Description 2", 2));
            noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 3", "Description 3", 3));

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY priority DESC") // '*' means all columns
    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();

}
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: Have you added the prepopulation logic after the app was installed? onCreate for Room doesn't happen on every app start-up, if you can clear data/uninstall and run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you have run the App without the code in the onCreate callback, or with code that failed, in the onCreate callback. The callback is only run after the database has been created. Once the database has been created, unless it is deleted, onCreate will not be called again.

The simplest option is to delete the database (easiest way is to uninstall the App) and then run the App and the onCreate callback will then be run.